# Angular Form Array Dynamic menu

Tags: angular, formarray, formgroups

[ hi everyone please help with Angular Dynamic html row Auto increment Menu,**(1)** firstly i want to Patch some of the fields on the menu by the dropdown button(Item), then push all values into Form Group by name of (**InvoiceLineItems**) ,**(2)** then push the Form group(**InvoiceLineItems**) as an Array Field inside Another Form Group by name of(**addCustomerInvoiceForm**). Please help code goes as following.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SchoolFeesService } from 'src/app/_services/school-fees.service';

class itemObject {
  item: any;
  unitPrice: number = 0;
  quantity: number = 0;

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-customer-invoice',
  templateUrl: './add-customer-invoice.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-customer-invoice.component.css']
})
export class AddCustomerInvoiceComponent implements OnInit {
  CustomerInvoice: CustomerInvoice[];
  addCustomerInvoiceForm: FormGroup;
  listOfFamilies: FamilyGroups[];
  listOfGuardians: Parent[];
  listOfSchoolFees: SchoolFees[];
  viewGuardians: boolean;
 itemTotal: number;

  itemObject=new itemObject()
  itemsArray: Array<itemObject> = [
    {item: "", unitPrice: 0, quantity: 0}
  ]

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private customerInvoiceService: CustomerInvoicesService,
    private familyGroupService: FamilyGroupsService,
    private guardianService: ParentService,
    private schoolFeeService: SchoolFeesService,
    private toastr: ToastrService, 
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getFamilyGroups();
    this.getSchoolFees();
    this.initializeForm();
    this.getItemTotal(this.itemObject);
    console.log(this.itemsArray)
  }




  initializeForm() {
    this.addCustomerInvoiceForm = this.fb.group ({
      DateRaised: ['', Validators.required],
      PaymentDueDate: ['', Validators.required],
      FamilyGroupId: [0, Validators.required],
      SubTotal: [],
      DiscountDescription: [],
      DiscountFactor: [],
      DiscountAmount: [],
      TotalDiscount: [],
      GrandTotal: [],
      invoiceLineItems: this.fb.array([])
     
    })
  }

  get invoiceLineItems(): FormArray {
    return this.addCustomerInvoiceForm.get("invoiceLineItems") as 
    FormArray
  }

  newInvoiceLineItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group ({
      schoolFeeId: '',
      description: '',
      quantity: '',
      unitPrice: '',
      totalAmount: [{value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.required],
      customerInvoiceId: '',
    })
  }


 addInvoiceLineItem() {
    this.invoiceLineItems.push(this.newInvoiceLineItem());
  }

  removeInvoiceLineItem(i: number) {
    this.invoiceLineItems.removeAt(i);
  }

 getSchoolFees() {
    this.schoolFeeService.getSchoolFees().subscribe((fees : any) =>{
      this.listOfSchoolFees = fees;
    })
  }

  getSchoolFessById(feesid){
    this.schoolFeeService.getSchoolFeeById(this.invoiceLineItems.
      controls['FamilyGroupId'].value).subscribe((fees : any) =>{
      this.listOfSchoolFees = fees;
    })
  }
}
`
```

```html
 <div *ngFor="let lineItem of invoiceLineItems.controls; let i = index">
    <span [formGroupName] = "i">
         <tr>
             <td>
              <button class="btn btn-error" type="button" 
                  (click)="removeInvoiceLineItem(i)">Remove</button>
              </td>
                   <td>
                      <small>Item</small>
                        <select class="form-control eezebiz-form-control- 
                          100" formControlName='schoolFeeId'style="width: 
                           100%" id="txt-line-item" tabindex="2"                                   
                          (change)="getSchoolFessById(
                           addCustomerInvoiceForm.
                           InvoiceLineItems.
                           controls['FamilyGroupId'].value)"
                           tabindex="1">

                           <option *ngFor="let fee of listOfSchoolFees" 
                            [ngValue]="fee.id">
                              {{ fee.feeCode }} | {{fee.Description }}
                           </option>
                          </select>
                        </td>
                         
                            <td>
                              <small>Quantity</small><br />
                               <app-text-inputsformControlName='quantity'
                                [label]='" quantity"' [id]='"txt- 
                                quantity"' [tabIndex]='"5"'>
                               </app-text-inputs>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <small>Unit Price</small><br />
                                <app-text-inputs 
                                formControlName='unitPrice'
                                [label]='"unitPrice"' [id]='"txt- 
                                unitPrice"' [tabIndex]='"5"'>
                                </app-text-inputs>
                           </td>

                            <td>
                                <small>Total Amount</small><br />
                                <app-text-inputs 
                                formControlName='totalAmount'
                                [label]='"totalAmount"' [id]='"txt- 
                                totalAmount"' [tabIndex]='"5"'
                                aria-readonly="true">
                                {{ addCustomerInvoice.totalAmount }}
                                </app-text-inputs>
                            </td>
            </tr>
       </span>
   </div>
```

Comment: Please post the code and not an image of the code.